# Linq compare before inserting to database

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

HI,

I have Ling Table with MyObject.

It has got fields:

Id
Number
Name

There is a method that adds ne MyObject to Database. In partial class MyOBject Im implementing OnValidate method. I need to check if there is already a row with such number and name.

The problem is where this values are nulls (for this example both can be)

```
var result = from m in myContext.MyObjects where m.Number == this.Number &&
m.Name == this.Name
select m;

if(result.Count > 0) {
   throw ...
}
```

if for example this.Name = null and r.Name = null and m.Number == this.Number no rows are selected and I dont know why :/

Any hints on how can I check if row with excactly the same values in fileds except Id (which is PK) are already in database ?

Thanks for help

Comment: I have Ling Table with MyObject. ? truly funny

Comment: Are you sure this.Number and this.Name have some values? Did you debug your code?

Comment: In DataContext there is an Object MyObject. Yes Im sure I debug. For example Number = null, Name = John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq-To-SQL has a problem when you give it an Equals expression with a nullable parameter that happens to be null - the query it creates is incorrect. You can read all about it here: http://riotingbits.com/2009/int-null-or-why-it-misbehaves-in-linq-to-sql/

You have to treat the cases where `this.Number` or `this.Name` are null separately.

```
IQueryable<MyObject> result = null;

if (this.Name == null && this.Number == null)
    result = from m in myContext.MyObjects
             where m.Name == null && m.Number == null
             select m;
else if (this.Name == null)
    result = from m in myContext.MyObjects
             where m.Name == null && m.Number == this.Number
             select m;
else if (this.Number == null)
    result = from m in myContext.MyObjects
             where m.Name == this.Name && m.Number == null
             select m;
else
    result = from m in myContext.MyObjects
             where m.Name == this.Name && m.Number == this.Number
             select m;
```

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of beacuse ion real world example there are much more fields to be checked :/ Anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = from m in myContext.MyObjects
               where (((m.Number == this.Number) || (m.Number == null)) &&
                     ((m.Name == this.Name) || (m.Name == null)))
               select m;
```

SQL query that LINQ generates would be:

```
SELECT Whatewer yourObject contains
FROM yourTable as [t0]
WHERE (([t0].[Number] = @p0) OR ([t0].[Number] IS NULL))
    AND (([t0].[Name] = @p1) OR ([t0].[Name] IS NULL))
```